# rest api jira - custom field

Tags: json, jira, jira-rest-api

I want to retrieve a customfield that has been setup in Jira. When I perform the below :

```
http://website/rest/api/2/issue/{ID}?expand=customfield_13201
```

i get the below .. e.g.

```
"customfield_13201": <a href=\"webpage"</a><br><br> <a href=\"webpage2" ... "
```

The result for the field is as a string encapsulted in many html tags. I can not make modification JIRA side.  Is there a work around or jira rest api that I could use to get the fields out in json format? .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use /rest/api/2/field: GET Returns a list of all fields, both System and Custom.

Comment: How to get the field schema attribute for example 

{
        "id": "customfield_21992",
        "name": "Manager",
        "custom": true,
        "orderable": true,
        "navigable": true,
        "searchable": true,
        "clauseNames": [
            "cf[21992]",
            "Manager"
        ],
        "schema": {
            "type": "user",
            "custom": "com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.customfieldtypes:userpicker",
            "customId": 21992
        }
    }
in above json , Schema type is User. now how can i get the User Schema attribute using rest api